# How to get first and second item of byte array

Tags: android, arrays, byte

I have a byte array from where I convert into a string like this:

```
ScanRecord scanRecord = result.getScanRecord();
            assert scanRecord != null;
            byte[] manufacturerData = scanRecord.getManufacturerSpecificData(0x0590);
            String puck_data = Arrays.toString(manufacturerData);
```

I retrieve 2 values in my string puck_data and I want to get the first and second values of my array. How can I do that?

Comment: manufacturerData[0] and manufacturerData[1] will have the first and second byte. To turn this into a String, if they are printable characters you can cast them to char, and append them to a StringBuilder for example.

Comment: could you give me the code for that? thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they printable characters?

Comment: yes like: [23, 26] if you mean this..

Comment: 23 and 26 are not printable characters, check the ascii table. So which sould be the output for those values?

Comment: these two are my desired values.. so i guess everything's okay.. thanks Juan

Answer (score 0):

As the example you set in comments are not printable characters, I think you want a way to print how the array looks like.

This example will show you the array contents converting the byte values to a decimal interpretation of them and give a basis on:

-Accessing the bytes in the array.
-How to convert a binary value to a decimal unsigned string representation.
-How to use StringBuilder.

```
        byte[] manufacturerData = new byte [] {(byte) 254,26};
        byte byte1 = manufacturerData[0];
        byte byte2 = manufacturerData[1];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[")
        .append((int) (0x00FF & byte1))
        .append(",")
        .append((int)  (0x00FF & byte2))
        .append("]");

        String puck_data = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(puck_data);
```